# What is the reason for the 'list object is not callable' error here?

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, dataset, pathlib

I'm trying to count the number of images inside a directory, sub-directories included.

```
import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path('images')
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('**/*')))
print(image_count)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-209-58f15b03e2f2> in <module>
      1 import pathlib
      2 data_dir = pathlib.Path('images')
----> 3 image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('**/*')))
      4 print(image_count)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have run your code it gives an empty list and image_count = 0

Comment: @AliHasanAhmedKhan I too pondered a lot over it and ended up finding no error with the code. I guess the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Yes i think you are right